# Integration Test On Child Process

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, integration-testing

I have a node js module that I'm using to launch a child process that calls a python script for sending emails. I'm trying to figure how I can write an integration test that can test that the correct email text is generated depending on the inputs that I give to my javascript code. Is there a tool that I can use that could call the javascript code and then intercept an email sent from a child process?

Comment: Can you post the code you've already written?

Comment: This is no longer an issue. I decided to use a mail service with a javascript interface api so I no longer have to test this.